# Shifting or stretching a float

Tags: floats, positioning

I have got a float, that is minimal too high for a page.

Is it possible to either shift it up a bit, so that it fits between the `head`- and `footsepline` or to stretch it with, say `0.9`?

My float actually is an algorithm from `algorithm2e`.

```
\documentclass[oneside,headsepline,footsepline]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

avoid scaling tables, this fits if you move it slightly:

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,headsepline,footsepline]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\vspace*{-18pt}
\begin{tabular}{c}
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\\This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.
\end{tabular}

\vspace*{-26pt}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works with `\begin{algorithm}[H]` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this question is still interesting for general floats, but for `algorithm`s the `adjustbox` package helps at stretching!

Be aware, that using the option `H` might influence the order this `algorithm` will appear when set with others. You might use `H` for every `algorithm`.

```
\documentclass[oneside,headsepline,footsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{totalheight=\textheight}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
This is a looooooooooooooooooooong sentence.\;
\end{algorithm}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```